# React-native: Port related error

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run an app on emulator and I see this error -

[image]

I did run the command react-native start in the other terminal and the packager is up and running on 8081 .

Any idea what the issue could be of ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There must be syntax error where you may be defining a property called 'name' twice. Try to check it.

Comment: I'm new to the react-native programming and not sure which file/where to check as the error does not really point to the file .

Comment: I will help you better if you can show me some code or your index.android.js code.

Answer (score 0):

This is index.android.js

```js
/* @flow */

/**
 * Android index
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
} = React;

/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */

var MobileApp = require('./components/Index');

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MobileApp', () => MobileApp);
```

And this is how index.js look like

```js
/* @flow */

/**
 * Index with route mapper
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  View,
  AppRegistry,
  Navigator,
  AsyncStorage,
} = React;

var settings = require('../config/settings'),
  apiErrors = require('../stores/ApiErrors.json'),
  Util = require('../utils/Util');

//Components
var Accounts = require('./Accounts'),
  ActivityDashboard = require('./ActivityDashboard'),
  Advice = require('./Advice'),
  Dashboard = require('./Dashboard'),
  History = require('./History'),
  HealthQuiz = require('./HealthQuiz'),
  HealthQuizCover = require('./HealthQuizCover'),
  HealthQuizResult = require('./HealthQuizResult'),
  HumanAPIConnect = require('./HumanAPIConnect'),
  HumanConnectCordovaTest = require('./HumanConnectCordovaTest'),
  LogIn = require('./LogIn'),
  ManualAdd = require('./ManualAdd'),
  MedicalInfo = require('./MedicalInfo'),
  Overview = require('./Overview'),
  Records = require('./Records'),
  SignUp = require('./SignUp'),
  WelcomeScenes = require('./WelcomeScenes');

if (settings.mode === 'dev') {

}

var RouteMapper = function(route, navigator) {
  //Log route name
  console.log('Route: ' + route.name);

  if (route.name === 'Accounts') {
    return (
      <Accounts navigator={navigator} />
    );
  }
  else if (route.name === 'ActivityDashboard') {
    return (
      <ActivityDashboard navigator={navigator} />
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'Advice') {
    return (
      <Advice navigator={navigator}
        component={route.component}
      />
    )
  } else if (route.name === 'Dashboard') {
    return (
      <Dashboard navigator={navigator}
        component={route.component}
      />
    )
  } else if (route.name === 'HealthQuiz') {
    return (
      <HealthQuiz navigator={navigator} />
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'HealthQuizCover') {
    return (
      <HealthQuizCover navigator={navigator} />
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'HealthQuizResult') {
    return (
      <HealthQuizResult navigator={navigator}
        result={route.result}
      />
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'History') {
    return (
      <History navigator={navigator}
        component={route.component}
        metric={route.metric}
      />
    )
  } else if (route.name === 'HumanAPIConnect') {
    return (
      <HumanAPIConnect navigator={navigator} />
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'HumanConnectCordovaTest') {
    return (
      <HumanConnectCordovaTest navigator={navigator} />
    );
  } else if(route.name === 'LogIn') {
    return (
      <LogIn navigator={navigator} />
    );
  }  else if (route.name === 'LogOut') {
    AsyncStorage.multiRemove(['email', 'username', 'auth', 'gender', 'age']);
    console.log('Route: LogIn');

    return (
      <LogIn navigator={navigator} />
    );
  } else if(route.name === 'ManualAdd') {
    return (
      <ManualAdd navigator={navigator} />
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'MedicalInfo') {
    return (
      <MedicalInfo navigator={navigator} />
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'Overview') {
    return (
      <Overview navigator={navigator}
        mainSelection={true}
      />
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'Records') {
    return (
      <Records navigator={navigator}
        component={route.component}
        collection={route.collection}
      />
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'SignUp') {
    return (
      <SignUp navigator={navigator} />
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'WelcomeScenes') {
    return (
      <WelcomeScenes navigator={navigator}/>
    );
  }
};

var Index = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {};
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(['username', 'auth', 'gender', 'age']).then((values) => {
      var username = values[0][1],
        auth = values[1][1],
        gender = values[2][1],
        age = values[3][1],
        urlPattern = '/auth/confirm-auth/';

      if (!(username && auth && gender && age)) {
        console.log('No username and/or auth were found');
        this.setState({initialRoute: 'LogIn'});
      } else {
        this.setState({'username': username, 'auth': auth});
        Util.fetchAPIData(null, username, auth, urlPattern, null, this._handleAPIResponse,
          this._onMissingConnection, this._handleFetchError, false);
      }
    }).done();
  },

  _onMissingConnection: function() {
    this.setState({initialRoute: 'LogIn'});
  },

  _handleFetchError: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    this.setState({initialRoute: 'LogIn'});
  },

  _handleAPIResponse: function(responseData) {
    //Set initial route depending on whether or not credentials are valid
    var initialRoute = (responseData.error == apiErrors.noError) ? 'Overview' : 'LogIn';
    this.setState({initialRoute: initialRoute});
  },

  render: function() {

    //For debugging purposes
    if (settings.mode === 'dev') {
      return (
        <Navigator
          initialRoute={{
            name: 'Accounts'
          }}
          renderScene={RouteMapper}
        />
      );
    }

    if (!('initialRoute' in this.state)) {
      return <View/>;
    }

    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{
          name: this.state.initialRoute
        }}
        renderScene={RouteMapper}
      />
    );
  },

});


module.exports = Index;
```

Comment: try to remove the if (settings.mode === 'dev') block and run it. The redefinition of the property called 'name' may be happening on your render().

Comment: Hi Franz , Thanks for the help but that did not work :( Is there anything else that I could try ?